# Permission denied error when copying to /usr/local/bin

Tags: macos

The GitHub setup page at https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git has a section on password caching.  It states to download the osxkeychain and copy it to /usr/local/bin.  I downloaded the file, but get a permission denied error when I try to copy it to the directory specified.  How can I get this file copied?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to use `sudo cp` instead of just `cp` to copy a file to `/usr/local/bin` because `/usr/*` is only writable for root.

Comment: Thank you.  I am a Mac/UNIX newbie, but trying to learn.